# How do I dynamically populate slingshot/plank

Tags: wingpanel, plank, slingshot, navigation

eOS by default do not allow shortcuts or files to be added on desktop. That's nice. I know there is a workaround to fix this. And I did and ended up with an ugly desktop.

Now, I have a better idea that I will like to try to implement myself. What if the application menu (aka slingshot) rearrange itself in most/last used app first, so I don't have to scroll via categories or alphabetically.

OR, populate plank automatically with last or most used apps, along with the icons forced to stay on the dock.

Edit: I am trying to hack the panel myself, GUIDE ME where to look at! -

#### Therefore I am not trying to post a feature request or a bug report, but I just want to ask *if and how* these changes are possible .

Thanks.

Comment: feature request are off-topic here - try https://launchpad.net/slingshot instead

Comment: @cipricus It's not a feature request. It's an Idea I am trying to implement. Sorry if i mislead you.

Comment: Then your answer should not be closed as a feature request or bug report. -- But then I think there are two problems here. **First**, I think you have two separate questions that you should post separately: (1) how to hack slingshot and (2) how to hack Plank; and **second**: your question(s) should start  with ***"how to"*** but with ***"is it possible to"***  - while chances are the answer to both is ***NO***.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Slingshot** provides some level of synapse integration, you should be able to search for recently (or frequently) run applications. You might want to implement a third view (view is "as grid" and "as category") that puts the applications based on your criteria.
2. **Plank** You have a `Keep in dock` option when you right-click on the icons in plank. As for automatic population, running apps appear there so you can easily "bookmark" them for later use with `Keep in dock`.